# Consistent family of measures and Bochner Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Suppose $W_{n}(x)$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to $\mathbb{C}$ which is positive-definite. By Bochner's Theorem, there exists an unique borel probability measure $\mu_{n}$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $$W_{n}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}e^{i\langle y,x\rangle}d\mu_{n}(y)$$
Now, if $m > n$, we can apply the same reasoning. Besides, because of of the uniqueness of $\mu_{n}$ in Bochner's Theorem, if $x = (x_{1},...,x_{n},0,...,0)\in \mathbb{R}^{m}$ we would expect $$W_{m}(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{m}}e^{i\langle y,x\rangle}d\mu_{m}(x) = W_{n}(x) \hspace{1cm} (1)$$
once $W_{m}$ does not have dependence in the $n+1,...,m$ entries of $x$.

$\textbf{Questions}$: 
1) Does (1) really holds and how can I prove it?
2) If (1) holds, does this imply the sequence of measures $\{\mu_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is consistent?

REMARK: For completeness, a family $\{\mu_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ of measures on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ if $\mu_{m}(A\times\mathbb{R}^{m-n})=\mu_{n}(A)$ if $m>n$ and $A$ a borel set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: It certainly holds for all $x'\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (the first $n$ coordinates) by Bochner's theorem there, so write $x=x'+z$ where $z$ is in the $n+1,\cdots,m$ coordinates, and use the fact that your measure is constant along those extra coordinates.

Comment: this is what botters me. Each $\mu_{n} $ is a measure on $\mathbb{R}^{n} $. How am i supposed to know that these measures are constant along the extra coordinates? They would be if they were product measures but this is not the case...